# Building FFMpeg Error in IOS6.1 unable to create an executable file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ffmpeg

I am trying to build ffmpeg on iOS6.1 (armv7), when I try to run ./configure like this:

```
./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
--disable-ffserver    --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin    --cc=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc    --as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc'   
--sysroot=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
--cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7'    --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -isysroot /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk'
--enable-pic
```

I get the following error:

> /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc is unable to
>   create an executable file. C compiler test failed.

Could somebody please provide the correct parameters in iOS6.1?

**Update Command :**

> ./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
>   --disable-ffserver --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin --cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2
>   --as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2'
>   --sysroot=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
>   --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -isysroot
>   /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk'
>   --enable-pic

**Error in Update Command :**

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2
>   is unable to create an executable file. C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.

Comment: earlier your sysroot and isysroot were pointing to iPhoneOS5.1. Now that you've changed them to iPhoneOS6.1 (which is the correct path) try again using `--cc=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc` instead of the arm-apple-darwin10...

Answer (score 2):

You are using...

```
--cc=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
```

That's wrong for armv7, you should be doing...

```
--cc=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1
```

Change the above to whatever `arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-x.x.x` version you have that `bin` folder.

As well, change the gas-preprocessor's target compiler to the same.

```
--as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1'
```

Additionally, don't put an `-arch armv7` in your `--extra-cflags`, you don't need it and you may get an error: `unrecognized command line option "-arch"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have changed the parameters as you mentioned. But Still i'm getting the same error. Please check my new command in Question(Update command: Section) Can you please guide what's wrong in that?

Comment: Make sure you're actually suppose to even be in `/applications/xcode.app/contents/...`. For example my compilers are in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1`. You should go into `Finder` then do shift+cmd+G, copy in `/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/` or `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/` to see which gives a positive result then let me know.

Comment: @ cube - Both the paths are working in "Go to Folder". Check my screen shot here : http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2013-07-10_at_8.50.47_AM-FLhOwODp.png Here the shortcut link is referenced for executable file. Original arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 path comes here : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/ Anyway i have tried, but it's still not working. Check my screen shot here : http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2013-07-10_at_9.03.38_AM-pa3sXrx7.png and code here http://pastebin.com/7LbzYjSM . Please check it.